# Building a python plugin on qgiq 2.6.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

I'm about creating a python plugin for my project , I already compiled it but I'm now facing a real problem while the installation , it seems to me that  there is issue about the version but I'm not sure ... this is the error O get :

Impossible de charger l'extension dataexporter provoque une erreur lors de l'appel de sa méthode classFactory()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 208, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/soukaina/.qgis2/python/plugins\dataexporter__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .dataexporter import dataexporter
ImportError: cannot import name dataexporter

Version de Python :
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Version de QGIS :
2.6.0-Brighton Brighton, exported

Chemin vers Python : ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/soukaina/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/soukaina/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg']

Comment: We need to see the code of dataexporter.py

Answer (score 2):

It seems like something is wrong with your `__init__` file.
First you have to name it only `__init__.py` and it should 
contain

```
def classFactory(iface):
    from YourPlugin import PluginName
     return PluginName(iface)
```

If you are new to programming plugins you should follow the 
qgis cookbook [How to write a Qgis plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#writing-a-plugin)

If you follow this steps there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with this and i figured that while you are on the OSGeo4W console, after you compile it with this command: pyrcc4 -o resources.py  resources.qrc THEN all i did was type: make test

then the next time i started QGIS i got no errors whatsoever. hope this helps